# I want to see the result of my query as 'pass' or 'fail' based on the condition

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I want to write a case statement where i can see the result in one line "PASS" or "FAIL" based on condition.

```
select max(a.ODS_Process_Timestamp) from ODS.DW_COUNTRY a where a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG=1;
```

output of this is

`06-FEB-19 06.25.40.000000000 AM`

```
select a.ODS_Process_Timestamp,a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG from ODS.DW_COUNTRY a 
where a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG=1 group by a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG,a.ODS_Process_Timestamp;
```

output of this is

```
ODS_Process_Timestamp                    ODS_CURRENT_FLAG

06-FEB-19 06.25.40.000000000 AM          1
```

Now I want to have a case statement where I will compare first query max(a.ODS_Process_Timestamp) is equal to 2nd query ODS_Process_Timestamp , so its a pass case else fail.

```
 select case when 
 (select max(a.ODS_Process_Timestamp) from ODS.DW_COUNTRY a where 
 a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG=1)=(l.ODS_Process_Timestamp from
 (select a.ODS_Process_Timestamp,a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG from ODS.DW_COUNTRY a 
 where a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG=1 group by 
 a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG,a.ODS_Process_Timestamp)l)
 then 'Pass' else 'Fail' 
 end as Timestamp_validation from ODS.DW_COUNTRY;
```

Expected result should be like

```
Timestamp_validation - PASS
```

Comment: 1 AD Andorra Europe ROW No No 01-JAN-00 12.00.00.000000000 AM 31-DEC-18 12.00.00.000000000 AM 0 08-MAR-16 08.35.00.322125000 PM 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want but here is a guess. My thought is that you are trying to see if the max ODS_Process_Timestamp for all rows is equal to ODS_Process_Timestamp on the one row with ODS_CURRENT_FLAG=1.

```
create table DW_COUNTRY
(ODS_Process_Timestamp timestamp,
 ODS_CURRENT_FLAG number);

insert into DW_COUNTRY values (systimestamp,1);
insert into DW_COUNTRY values (systimestamp,1);
insert into DW_COUNTRY values (systimestamp,1);
commit;
--host sleep 1
--insert into DW_COUNTRY values (systimestamp,0);
--commit;


select case when 
(select 
 max(a.ODS_Process_Timestamp) 
 from DW_COUNTRY a)=
(select max(ODS_Process_Timestamp)
 from DW_COUNTRY a 
 where a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG=1)
then 'Pass' else 'Fail' 
end as Timestamp_validation 
from dual;
```

Uncomment the commented lines to see it fail.

Edited to handle multiple rows with flag=1.

Bobby

Comment: I want the same as you suggested but after doing some change to your query I am getting multiple rows but I need only one rows saying timestamp_validation=pass

Comment: Pass
Pass
Pass
Pass
Pass
Pass
Pass
Pass

Comment: Ok. I edited it to take the max timestamp out of all the rows where the flag is 1. I'm just not sure what you want.

Comment: select case when (
select 
 max(a.ODS_Process_Timestamp) 
 from DW_COUNTRY a where a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG=1)=(select l.ODS_Process_Timestamp from
(select a.ODS_Process_Timestamp,a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG from ODS.DW_COUNTRY a where a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG=1 group by a.ODS_Process_Timestamp,a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG)l)
then 'Pass' else 'Fail' 
end as Timestamp_validation 
from ODS.DW_COUNTRY a;

Comment: The above query worked but i am getting too many rows of pass. Also I want to compare max of timestamp and timestamp value with group by on flag 1.ie i will get 1 data when i groupby on flag 1 as it is same.

Comment: select case when (
select 
 max(a.ODS_Process_Timestamp) 
 from DW_COUNTRY a where a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG=1)=(select l.ODS_Process_Timestamp from
(select a.ODS_Process_Timestamp,a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG from ODS.DW_COUNTRY a where a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG=1 group by a.ODS_Process_Timestamp,a.ODS_CURRENT_FLAG)l)
then 'Pass' else 'Fail' 
end as PROCESS_TIMESTAMP_Validation 
from dual; ------------This one worked.                                                                                                  Thanks

Comment: select l.ODS_PRIMARYKEY from
(select a.ODS_PRIMARYKEY , a.COUNTRYCODE, a.COUNTRYNAME, a.MARKETINGREGION as New_Region,case when a.MARKETINGREGION='North America'
then 'Pass' else 'Fail' 
end as Result_MARKETINGREGION 
from DW_COUNTRY a where a.ods_current_flag=1 and a.COUNTRYNAME in ('United States','Canada'))l where l.Result_MARKETINGREGION='Fail';                                      The query output is nothing which i expect. so how can I show a pass if output of query is nothing.

Comment: yes, it worked . I just change the according to your suggestion and it worked.